# Experience editor - not able to edit renderings or make changes to page layouts

Tags: experience-editor

We are using `Sitecore 9.3` and facing issues with the experience editor only for some specific page items. We are unable to make any edits to the renderings in the Experience editor (Basically the editor tools are not showing up). Placeholder settings are configured correctly and working for other pages. When inspecting the browser we could see the below console errors. We are facing this issue only for experience editor.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Sitecore.PageModes.ChromeManager.hoverFrame() is undefined
```

Note: we are using `Vue.js` for our front end.

[image: Console errors in Experience editor]

Comment: Is there any JS coming on these pages that is creating the issue?

Comment: Did you add any component that has animation like a slider?

Comment: @praveensoni we dont have any animations or sliders in this page.

Comment: @SumitBhatia the error is coming from "sitecore/shell/Applications/Page Modes/Output/4255514063022039022.JS:3844"

Comment: @Prem2530 Did you try with the page without any component?

Comment: if you are using Vue.js - how have you enabled Experience Editor support? Is this a JSS headless application?

Comment: Seems like your Custom jquery code is causing the issue. disable your custom jquery code and view the page to make sure it works.

Comment: @SumitBhatia yes I tried , finally found the component which is causing the issue. Surprisingly removing and adding back the same component fixed the issue.

Comment: @Prem2530 Great, If you think my answer was helpful, kindly accept the answer so it can be helpful for others. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned that the issue is showing for some specific items, so the issue is looking like any JS is conflicting with the JS of the experience editor. You can do the following.

1. Check the page by removing all the components and see if it is created by any specific component?
2. If you find any jquery code, try to use jQuery in your code in the NoConflict mode as jQuery uses the $ sign but Sitecore also, which could cause conflicts.

Use this thread for more details as it looks like a conflict issue to me.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198315/sitecore-page-editor-javascript-error

Answer (score 1):

As Sumit mentions, it sounds like one of your components is bringing in conflicting or bad javascript. Which is causing the OTB sitecore scripts to fail to render parts of the experience editor.

My suggestion would be to duplicate the problematic item first. Then remove the components one at a time using the **content editor** (*start doing this with components that are not included in the working pages*).

You can do this by going to:

`Presentation tab => Details => Final Layout => Controls => Edit *(select component to remove and save)`*

Then go again to the experience editor to see if the problem occurs. If it does remove another, and another etc.

Alternatively, what sometimes helps is to create a new **Empty Layout**. Which is essentially a stripped-down Cshtml view, with just basic HTML and top-level placeholders (maybe add minimal js assets like jquery, etc).

```
<html>
  <body>
    @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("Content")
  </body>
</html>
```

Then set that layout for the duplicated item. That should hopefully restore the EE controls.

Then start looking in the console to see if any errors and again start removing components till you find the culprit.