# Experience Editor is not working in 10.2

Tags: experience-editor

Recently we migrated from sitecore 9.2 to 10.2.
After deploying all the custom code, everything else seems to be working except Experience Editor.
It gives below error in browser console:

[image]

I compared all the js appearing in console error with js files in vanilla instance.
All of them are exactly the same.
Can anyone please suggest what could be the possible reason for this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you replace your ExperienceEditor.js file from your vanilla instance? Here is the location `sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\ExperienceEditor\ExperienceEditor.js`

Comment: Yes Sumit. I replaced ExperienceEditor.js file but the issue is still the same.

Comment: If you create a blank page without any component and open it, is it showing the same issue?

Comment: Yes even then it is same. Even if I open Sitecore default(which is there in vanilla) page, then also  it throws the same errors in browser console.

Comment: Can you try creating and apply an empty layout as here: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/34165/experience-editor-not-able-to-edit-renderings-or-make-changes-to-page-layouts/34179#34179 does error still occur?

Comment: It can happen when your custom is conflicts with Sitecore js. Try removing the reference to custom js to start with

Comment: Remove all your custom js and then test the page if it breaks. If not, find the culprit js and fix it.